# Issue while applying Logistic regression on csv Data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I am new to machine learning and am trying to learn it using scala and spark in local mode, my requirement is to apply Logistic Regression on a Csv Data.

Example of CSV Data:

> ```
> id    normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours    normalized_merchant_fraud_risk  normalized_time_since_last_transaction  normalized_average_transaction  normalized_days_till_expiration normalized_transaction_time normalized_change_in_merchant_sales Amount  Class
> 0 -1.034133845    -0.513680076    -0.508604693    -2.196178501    -0.108862958    -1.061008629    0.285154155 135.75  0
> 1 -1.265759551    0.07327929  1.311443586 -0.734940773    1.450278841 -0.801969386    0.860978154 1.98    0
> 2 2.240560126 -1.509744002    -0.689632426    -1.622658556    -1.434514451    -0.419166831    -1.36019318 24  0
> 3 -22.32205074    -22.20892648    -8.997418067    3.396521112 1.155982154 -0.7160386  3.832327638 212 0
> 4 -0.522512757    0.81919506  1.777105544 1.013635885 0.306739941 -0.06426399 0.32108437  19.99   0
> 5 -2.089682661    0.849492313 0.790108223 -0.590925467    0.434408367 -0.805684103    0.523183012 3.99    0
> 6 -2.647158204    1.763548392 0.490936849 1.541377437 -0.949784452    -0.336538438    -0.706230268    9.46    0
> 7 -0.4630152  0.32577193  -0.139411116    -0.90596587 0.959955945 -0.809819817    1.687780067 149.95  0
> 8 -1.386557134    -1.320988511    1.579036707 -3.062784171    -0.437193393    -0.095830087    0.373993105 154 0
> 9 0.97974056  -0.420226839    1.036644229 0.580934286 -1.175975734    -0.445575941    -0.505391954    100.78  0
> ```

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
       .appName("Simple Application")
       .master("local[*]")
       .getOrCreate()
    val csvData = spark.read.format("csv")
       .option("header", "true")
       .option("inferschema", "true")
       .load("file:///F:/test.csv")

    csvData.printSchema

    var cols = Array("id", "normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours",
        "normalized_merchant_fraud_risk",
        "normalized_time_since_last_transaction",
        "normalized_average_transaction",
        "normalized_days_till_expiration",
        "normalized_transaction_time",
        "normalized_change_in_merchant_sales", "Amount")

    var assembler = new VectorAssembler()
       .setInputCols(cols)
       .setOutputCol("features")
    val pipeline=new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler))
    val df=pipeline.fit(csvData).transform(csvData)
    df.show(1)

    val splits=df.randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.2),seed=11L)
    val training=splits(0).cache()
    val test=splits(1)

    val lr=new LogisticRegression()
       .setMaxIter(10)
       .setRegParam(0.3)
       .setFeaturesCol("features")
       .setLabelCol("Class")
    val lrModel=lr.fit(training)
    val predictions=lrModel.transform(training)
    predictions.show()
  }
}
```

I want to use label column as Class and the rest column as my features column in the above dataset.

I am getting the below error in the above code:-
Below is the console stack trace:-

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.runtime.LazyRef, value: LazyRef thunk)
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2:(Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Lscala/runtime/LazyRef;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$1916/120999784, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$1916/120999784@2905b568)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(named_struct(id_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(id#10 as double), normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount, Amount#18, Class_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(Class#19 as double))))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, UDF(named_struct(id_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(id#10 as double), normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount, Amount#18, Class_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(Class#19 as double))) AS features#42)
    - element of array (index: 10)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 11)
    - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(id#10, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount#18, Class#19, UDF(named_struct(id_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(id#10 as double), normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount, Amount#18, Class_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(Class#19 as double))) AS features#42))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec, name: projectList, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec, Project [id#10, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount#18, Class#19, UDF(named_struct(id_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(id#10 as double), normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount, Amount#18, Class_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(Class#19 as double))) AS features#42]
+- FileScan csv [id#10,normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11,normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12,normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13,normalized_average_transaction#14,normalized_days_till_expiration#15,normalized_transaction_time#16,normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17,Amount#18,Class#19] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/F:/test.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours:double,normalized_merchant_fraud_risk:double,n...
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec, Sort [id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_average_transaction#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_days_till_expiration#15 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_transaction_time#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17 ASC NULLS FIRST, Amount#18 ASC NULLS FIRST, Class#19 ASC NULLS FIRST, features#42 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Project [id#10, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount#18, Class#19, UDF(named_struct(id_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(id#10 as double), normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours, normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk, normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12, normalized_time_since_last_transaction, normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13, normalized_average_transaction, normalized_average_transaction#14, normalized_days_till_expiration, normalized_days_till_expiration#15, normalized_transaction_time, normalized_transaction_time#16, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales, normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17, Amount, Amount#18, Class_double_vecAssembler_a001d143dede, cast(Class#19 as double))) AS features#42]
   +- FileScan csv [id#10,normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours#11,normalized_merchant_fraud_risk#12,normalized_time_since_last_transaction#13,normalized_average_transaction#14,normalized_days_till_expiration#15,normalized_transaction_time#16,normalized_change_in_merchant_sales#17,Amount#18,Class#19] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/F:/test.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,normalized_total_spent_last_24_hours:double,normalized_merchant_fraud_risk:double,n...
)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 9)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function2.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.$anonfun$doExecute$4$adapted:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodeAndComment;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetric;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$1400/863366099, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$1400/863366099@191f4d65)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Note :- The problem was solved after changing the scala version to 2.11 from 2.12

Comment: If you found a solution on your own, you may consider answering your own question with as much detail as possible (e.g. spark and scala versions, before and after resolving the issue). It could help others who'd face the same Exception in the future.

Comment: sure i will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this issue is mainly occured due to scala version, my current spark version is 2.4 and earlier i was using scala version 2.12.3 later on to resolve the issue i tried replacing the scala library version by 2.11 in my project build path, i have also observed this issue mainly occurs when we are using spark in local mode and scala with maven and eclipse,i hope this answer helps someone who is facing the same issues, cheers and happy coding.